# Why does this datagrid sort in a weird order?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

I have a datagrid where each row has a column where I have defined a formatter to format the display result depending on what it says in the database and create a `div` with a background color depending on the database.

I have this structure for my datagrid:

```
structure: [
  {
    name: "Name",
    field: "name",
    width: "auto"
  },
  {
    name: "Initials",
    field: "initials"
  },
  {
    name: "E-mail",
    field: "email",
    width: "auto"
  },
  {
    name: "Kerberos",
    field: "kerberos",
    width: "120px",
    formatter: function(kerberos){
      var format = "";

      if(kerberos == "password expired" || kerberos == "account expired"){
        format = '<div class="yellow" title="'+kerberos+'">'+kerberos+'</div>';
      }else if(kerberos == "ok"){
        format = '<div class="green" title="'+kerberos+'">'+kerberos+'</div>';
      }else{
        format = '<div class="red" title="Has no kerberos account">not available</div>';
      }

      return format;
    }
},
```

When I press the column header to sort, it sorts the rows, put not consistent, so I don't know if it sorts correctly (see image below). How do I define the way the datagrid have to sort this column?

[image: How it sorts]

I was thinking it was the HTML `<div...>` part I do in the formatter due to the `<>` characters, but it still sorts weird if I only output the text (which by my understanding, should be sorted alphabetically). Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

***EDIT:***
forgot to add how i get/assign data. I get a lot of data from a xhr.post in JSON format, then i do as follows:

```
dojo.xhr.post({
    url: "/cgi-bin/users.cgi",
    handleAs: "json",
    content: {
      psearch: "dojoXhrBlank"
    },
    load: function(jsondata){
      // Creating a store for the datagrid
      var personStore = new Memory({ data: jsondata });

      // Create datastore for datagrid
      var gridStore = ObjectStore({objectStore: personStore});
      ...
```

Comment: just tried to input numbers (1, 2 and 3) instead of pure text... It still sorts the same as the image above. I don't understand, could the datagrid be sorting based on both the "kerberos" column and another column? Just think it would be wired since i haven't defined that anywhere :/

Comment: Can see im looking for some equivilent to comparatorMap. I tried to use comparatorMap on the data grid (Ex: myGrid.comparatorMap["kerberos"] = function(a,b){};) but i didn't fix my sorting problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. The problem lies in `ObjectStore`. This store (for some reason) wont sort properly and after changing the store type to `ItemFileReadStore` it sortet properly. The other reason for switching store was that `ItemFileReadStore` also supports the `comparatorMap` attribute which allows for custom sorting, `ObjectStore` dose not support this attribute.

solution:

```
load: function(jsondata){      
      var store = new ItemFileReadStore({
        data: { identifier: "id", items: jsondata }
      });

      pgrid = new DataGrid({
        store: store,
        ...
```